# How to get the milliseconds of the beginning of today?

Tags: python, time

I can get current time in milliseconds as follows:

```
import time
timestamp = int(time.time()*1000.0)
```

However, how can I get the milliseconds of the beginning of today, e.g. 09/09/2018 00:00 ?

Comment: Before downvoting, dear children, please make some efforts to read the question.

Comment: got it sir, I have been finding the solutions. tricky one buck of less documentation of time.time() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
int(pd.to_datetime(datetime.datetime.now().date()).value / 1000000)
# Outputs: 1536451200000
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works to get the required start of the date's time in milliseconds in `Python 3`

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_obj = datetime.strptime('09.09.2019 00:00',
                           '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
millisec = dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000

print(millisec)

Output>> 1568001600000.0
```

Comment: @Markus you need to mention from which day you want . Yes, I hardcoded the date. If you want to automate, you can do that as well with a list of replacement time series.

Comment: I said `beginning of today, for example ...`. Sorry if it was not clear enough.